# Incoming email rule to filter mail sent exclusively to one contact group

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365, email-filter

I need to filter emails sent to one particular contact group (distribution list) to the exclusion of any other recipient or group. For example, mail sent to *Some Group* should be filtered, but mail sent to *Some Group, Some Other Group* or *Some Group, someguy@somecompany.tld* should pass through unfiltered.

I can't seem to find a negation operator for recipient that would let me do that. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

According to my research, there is no rules to realize this, but we can create a search folder to only show emails to this specific group:

Please refer to following criteria:

[image]

[Use Search Folders to find messages or other Outlook items](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/use-search-folders-to-find-messages-or-other-outlook-items-c1807038-01e4-475e-8869-0ccab0a56dc5)

Answer (score 0):

This is the best solution I've found so far. I'm still hoping to hear of something more reliable. I'm assigning filtered messages to an Autodeleted category, which has a distinctive color, so I can scan the Deleted Items folder for false positives.

*What condition(s) do you want to check?*

- sent to people or public group [The Filtered Group]

*What do you want to do with the message?*

- assign it to the category [Autodeleted]
- move it to the specified folder [Deleted Items]

*Are there any exceptions?*

- except if sent to people or public group [Other Commonly Included Groups, Other Commonly Included Persons]